# How to load CSV to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv

Im using mysql and Php

I tried several times but always didnt insert data. please help me to do this.

I have MySQL table called 'db_master'. **'ID' feild is auto increment**

**[this is my table](http://oi54.tinypic.com/30xg9hc.jpg)**

and i have csv file called 'csv_master' - **no column headings..**

**[this is my csv file -](http://oi51.tinypic.com/30kue6p.jpg)**

please help me to input CSV file my table (db_master) - **PHP CODE REQUIRED**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using a graphical client like www.heidisql.com where you can use a dialog to assign the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './csv_master.csv' INTO TABLE your_db.db_master FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'my_file.csv'
INTO TABLE db_master(destination, bay, shipInvoiceNumber, invoiceNumber, start, end);
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has support for loading CSV data using the **Load Data** 
 command. You can find more help [here](http://support.modwest.com/content/6/253/en/how-do-i-import-delimited-data-into-mysql.html).

I noticed that you have an additional problem though. Your CSV file has fewer columns than your table - you may want to fix that first.

Chris

Comment: In an other hand a good old example is still nice to get instantly the idea :)