# how to Export data from csv file into mysql database?

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv

how to Export data from csv file into mysql database?
is there any Query or some othr way avial?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442285/please-help-me-to-load-csv-to-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean `IMPORT`., here's how:

```
load data local infile 'yourCSVfilepath.csv' into table tableNameHERE
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\r\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

To Export data to csv from Mysql use this

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/tablename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM tablename
```

To import csv to Mysql use this

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tablename.csv' INTO TABLE tablename
```